# Aquamacs + Auctex fontification issue

Tags: auctex

I use Aquamacs to edit tex files on two different Mac machines.  I really like some of Auctex's features, notably the way it formats in math mode to make things a bit easier to read.  A few weeks ago I noticed that on my MacBook running Ventura, Auctex's fontification does not automatically start when I type a "$"; it only applies after I type the ending "$".  I believe it wasn't always like this, and I find it pretty annoying.  My iMac does not have the same issue.  I tried doing a clean install of Aquamacs on the MacBook, and I still have the same issue.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, that change was necessary and can't be undone.  You can try this bit of code in your init file:

```el
(setq TeX-electric-math '("$" . "$"))
```

where the manual says:

> If the variable is non-nil and you type <kbd>$</kbd> outside math mode, AUCTeX
> will automatically insert the opening and closing symbols for an
> inline equation and put the point between them. The opening symbol
> will blink when blink-matching-paren is non-nil. If TeX-electric-math
> is nil, typing <kbd>$</kbd> simply inserts `$` at point, this is the default.

It should fix your point to some extent.